# Use AlarmManager to restart Activity periodically

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a REST API that considers the day of the week:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
Observable<List<String>> playlistObservable = playlistService.getPlaylist(id, day);
```

Which works fine. However, my application is supposed to run indefinitely for long hours.

Since I can not change where this code is, I was wondering if I could have an AlarmManager restart my "controller" after midnight.

If yes, how can I do this?

Comment: You cannot launch activities from the background, such as via `AlarmManager`, on modern versions of Android. "my application is supposed to run indefinitely for long hours" -- generally speaking, that is an anti-pattern on battery-powered devices. My recommendation is that you reconsider this plan.

Comment: It is targeted at TV devices, not mobile

Comment: AFAIK, that does not change the nature of Android.